# Issue in compiling with marshal.h : error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol

Tags: c++-cli

I am trying to use the marshalling library in my C++/CLI project. When compiled with `#include <msclr/marshal.h>` I get the error `error C2872: 'IServiceProvider' : ambiguous symbol`. Most of the resolutions seems to be suggesting moving `#include <windows.h>`
like the one here -> [Ambiguous references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712965%28VS.71%29.aspx), but I dont have those includes. All I have is:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Configuration;
using namespace std;
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
```

How do I debug this issue ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You do, indirectly, marshal.h includes it.  It dumps an enormous amount of identifiers in the global namespace.  The macros are especially awkward, lots of them match names used in the framework.

Lots of things that marshal.h does can be done by the Marshal class as well.  But I can't help you with that, you didn't mention why you want to use it.  You can solve this particular mishap by putting the #include directive *before* the using statements:

```
#include <msclr/marshal.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Configuration;
```

Comment: I am trying to convert String ^ to const char*

Comment: Marshal::StringToCoTaskMemAnsi + Marshal::FreeCoTaskMem.

Comment: Can also use System::String^ to avoid usings in header

Answer (score 16):

Make sure you only have the:

```
using namespace System;
```

in the cpp file of the CLR project and not in the header.
Visual studio automatically adds it to the header when creating a CLR class library project.
In the cpp itself, the includes must precede the "using namespace".

Comment: Indeed, this confirms once again that `using namespace` in header files is evil. Removing it from the header fixes the problem.