# How do you turn a System::String into std::string without marshalling?

Tags: c++, string, c++-cli, system

Every single post on the internet tells me to use marshalling. The thing is that marshalling just won't work on my Windows Forms Application. The library collides with the Windows forms or something like that "Ambiguous Symbol", i already tried putting them inside different namespaces, i already tried declaring the namespaces on a different cpp files, it just won't work. I'm developing a windows form application and i need to save the data on a txt using fstream, but i need my data on std::string otherwise fstream won't read it. But for whatever reason Windows forms just forces you to use their managed classes aka String^. Does anyone know a way i could accomplish this task? Please, i'll be so thankful.

My Header

```
#include "NewProject.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

This is my load method

```
    private: System::Void Interf_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    ifstream infile;
    bool fresh_start = false;
    infile.open("Data.txt", ios::binary);

    if (infile.fail()) {
        fresh_start = true;
        infile.close();
    }

    if (!fresh_start) {
        size_t index; infile >> index;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            string* temp = new string[5];

            for (size_t j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                infile >> temp[j];
            }
            String^ p1 = gcnew String(temp[0].c_str()); String^ p2 = gcnew String(temp[1].c_str());
            String^ p3 = gcnew String(temp[2].c_str()); String^ p4 = gcnew String(temp[3].c_str());
            String^ p5 = gcnew String(temp[4].c_str()); int valor = int::Parse(p5);

            apu->proyectos.Add(gcnew Project(p1, p2, p3, p4, valor));

        }
    }
```

This is to save.

```
private: System::Void button8_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

ofstream outfile;
outfile.open("Data.txt", ios::binary);
outfile << apu->proyectos.Count << "\n";

for (size_t i = 0; i < apu->proyectos.Count; i++) {

    std::string u1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(apu->proyectos[0]);
    std::string u2 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(apu->proyectos[1]);
    std::string u3 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(apu->proyectos[2]);
    std::string u4 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(apu->proyectos[3]);
    std::string u5 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(apu->proyectos[4]);

    std::string line(std::string(u1 + " " + u2 + " " + u3 + " " + u4 + " " + u5) + "\n");
    char* buffer = &line[0u];
    outfile.write(buffer, line.size());
}




Close();
```

}

Then i get 1082 errors about ambiguous symbols. My application works perfectly when i remove the Marshall stuff, so that's the culprit.

Comment: Get the bytes from the System::String and allocate a std::string? `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aString)` But you should really show us the code, so we can understand what you attempted so far. I think you're mixing up technologies in a bad way here.

Comment: Why do you have to save txt using fstream?

Comment: My intellisense has no idea about that. But hey man thanks for the tip i'll explore it later. Yeah my cod got really girt, i'll update it on the post.

Comment: Fstream is all over the web apparently it's the only thing that pops up for txt saving.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to use C++/CLR? Why not pure C++ or pure C# application?

Comment: When in Rome it is best to write code like a Roman.  Use the System::IO::StreamWriter class to write text files without having to write all that painful conversion code.  And look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000663/issue-in-compiling-with-marshal-h-error-c2872-iserviceprovider-ambiguous/4000759#4000759

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks fam, you saved my presentation.

Comment: @Bata To answer the question asked, even MSDN says that marshaling is the way to go: [How to: Convert System::String to Standard String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-system-string-to-standard-string?view=vs-2017), so if you are having trouble getting the code to compile then you are likely just using it incorrectly, but you didnt show that code.